# Syntax Error in if/else Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, logic, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error on this code but I don't know why.

```
$(".choose-one .monthly, .choose-one .yearly").live("click", function() {
    billing_selection();
});

function billing_selection() {
    if($(this).hasClass("yearly") {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".billing-options-hidden option:eq(1)").attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("doSomething");
    }
}
```

This is my first post, please be gentle.

Comment: Note that `this` in your function doesn't refer to the clicked element.

Comment: That's my next problem. Why doesn't `this` refer to the object clicked?

Comment: Because you are calling the function within the context of the handler, _`this` here refers to the element_, you can code, `$(".choose-one .monthly, .choose-one .yearly").live("click", billing_selection)`. That being said, note that `live` method is deprecated, you can use `on` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `missed` closing parenthesis

```
  if($(this).hasClass("yearly"))
                               ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Add missing paren:

```
// --------------------------v
if($(this).hasClass("yearly")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not closed `if` properly

```
   function billing_selection() {
    if($(this).hasClass("yearly") ){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".billing-options-hidden option:eq(1)").attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("doSomething");
    }
}
```